# What's the difference between .cs with top-level statements and .csx programs?

Tags: c#, .net, csx, dotnet-script

As mentioned, I was wondering what is the difference between C# program with only top-level statements and no namespace nor main class and a csx script.

I'm using dotnet-script right now and it behaves the same for both .cs and .csx and I'm a bit confused.

Comment: dotnet-script doesn't care about the filename extension, it will interactively execute both.  The one place where it matters is when you want to run the script directly by clicking on the file in a file manager.  Only a .csx file will automatically activate dotnet-script.

Answer (score 3):

Because `.csx` is intended for *scripting* without a whole project involved, it has support for a few directives that aren't necessary when you're working in the context of a project.

For example, there an `#r` directive to load a DLL, and a `#load` directive to load another `.csx` file. See the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/january/essential-net-csharp-scripting.

In a C# project, all the C# files included in the project are automatically loaded, and there are directives in the project file to include nuget packages, dlls, etc.

Comment: And: .cs with "only" top level statements still has a class and a main() "under the hood".